# ¿Es posible eliminar la etiqueta [store] permanentemente?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

La etiqueta [store](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/store) es ambigua y no aporta ninguna información. Debería ser eliminada ahora que estamos a tiempo (sólo hay [11 preguntas relacionadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/store))

- Describe el contenido de las preguntas en donde es aplicada la etiqueta ¿Es clara? --> El contenido es variado, desde preguntas de C, pasando por preguntas de swift, un procedimiento almacenado para MySQL, hasta problemas con apps en el Google Play store. Supongo que lo usan cuando quieren hablar de "almacenar" algo sin mucho detalle. Sea un dato en un arreglo, un registro en una BD o alguna cosa en una app. No aclara nada sobre la pregunta correspondiente.
- ¿Se encuentra el concepto en conformidad con el tema de la comunidad? --> Está on-topic (no habla de gaticos ni de bicicletas checoslovacas) pero es ambiguo, como se acaba de ver en el punto anterior. No aclara nada sobre la pregunta.
- ¿Añade la etiqueta algún contenido valioso a la aportación? --> No lo creo. Apunta a algo básico que no aclara nada sobre el código de la pregunta.
- ¿Significa lo mismo en todos los contextos comunes? --> La ambiguedad en su uso hace pensar que no significa lo mismo. No se sabe a qué concepto se refieren con store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He procedido a eliminar la etiqueta [store] de todas las preguntas en las que estaba, siguiendo el criterio que perfectamente ha detallado @fedorqui.

De momento como bien dice el, creo que no será necesario quemar la etiqueta, ya que su uso es mínimo. Si en el futuro vemos que esto es necesario, lo haremos.

Muchas gracias Alfabravo por reportarlo :)

Comment: Joer qué rápido eres :) Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en hacerlo, he eliminado también la etiqueta [tag:playstore].

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' pa eso me pagan ;) Entiendo que [tag:playstore] tenía pocas preguntas, asi que no crearemos un sinonimo de momento

Comment: Sí, apenas cuatro. ¡A mí no me pagaban! :P

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' hay que saber negociar :P

Comment: Me ausenté unos meses y al volver encontré un SO ultra eficiente! :) Gracias a todos

Answer (score 3):

Me parece bien, así como está planteada es demasiado ambigua. No creo que haya que ponerla en la lista negra, pues apenas 11 preguntas no sugiere que añadirla sea un error muy común.

Por el desglose de etiquetas complementarias parece evidente que a cada cual le sugiere una cosa:

1. Store para el lugar donde se suben las aplicaciones: Google Play y Apple Store.
2. Store para *stored procedure* de SQL.
3. Store como verbo.

Para 1. veo que ya existe [playstore](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playstore) y [google-play](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play) (que deberían unirse en favor de la segunda), por lo que solamente faltaría [apple-store](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-store) y proceder a reetiquetar.

Para 2. veo que ya existe [stored-procedure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stored-procedure) por lo que solamente hay que reetiquetar.

Para 3. simplemente hay que eliminarla.